# LightGBM Multi-classification prediction result

Tags: python, machine-learning, predict, multiclass-classification, lightgbm

I tried to build a multi-classification model using lightGBM. After training the model, I parsed some data online and put it into my model for prediction.

However, the result seems weird to me. 
I thought the nested array of my prediction means the probability for each class(I got 4 classes). The result of x-test (the data I used for validation) seems right. But the result of the data I scraped seems weird. It doesn't add up to 1.

[image: prediction result]

In this post [multiclass-classification-with-lightgbm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47370240/multiclass-classification-with-lightgbm), the prediction result didn't add up to 1 as well!

**The 2 dataframes look the same to me, and I am using exactly the same model! Can someone pls tell me how to interpret the result or what have I done wrong?**
[image: x-test dataframe]
[image: data I scraped dataframe]

Comment: Have you used the parameters correctly ?, Passing multiclass in objective and using softmax (Activation function) for probability calibration.

Comment: @Yash Kumar Atri Here's how I set my params `params = {
    'objective': 'multiclass',
    'boosting': 'gbdt',
    'num_class': 4,
    'num_leaves': 5,
    'max_depth': 5,
    'learning_rate': 0.003,
    'max_bin': 100,
    'is_unbalance': 'true',
}` I know multiclass use softmax to normalize the raw scores. Hope I don't get it wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multi-class classification, `when the classes are not mutually exclusive`, the sum of probabilities may not equal to one. Say for example you are classifying dog, cat, and bird in images but your model is shown a car image, the probabilities for the three classes should be low and not equal to 1. you need rescale the predictions using [this formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1009143) if you want to force the sum of probabilities to sum to 1.

On the other hand, when you have a classifier of type `1 vs others`, for example, the images can only be a cat, a dog, or a bird. In this case, the classes are mutually exclusive, and the probabilities should sum to 1.

More references [ref1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6599/calibrating-a-multi-class-boosted-classifier),[ref2](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/42568/should-estimated-probabilities-from-multi-class-classification-sum-to-1),[ref3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1009138/how-do-you-scale-a-set-of-number-such-that-they-sum-to-0-5-after-scaling)

Comment: So is it also possible for the probability to be larger than 1? All the probabilities I got in the 2nd scenario are larger than 1.

Comment: This should also apply when probabilities are more than 1. You need to resale your outputs

Comment: May I ask how is it possible for probability to be greater than 1? Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, it's very possible! in your context, what the model tries to do is to evaluate each class in a binary manner `1 vs 0 for each class`  so nothing is absurd here. Referring to the exclusivity rule that we talked about can help you a lot understand the concept. does that help?